# D3.js Mouse events between different SVG groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG structure as follows:

```
<svg>
   <g class="A">
      <rect id="A1" />
      <rect id="A2" />
      <rect id="A3" />
   </g>
   <g class="B">
      <rect id="B1" />
      <rect id="B2" />
      <rect id="B3" />
   </g>
   <g class="C">
      <rect id="C1" />
      <rect id="C2" />
      <rect id="C3" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

I am attempting to drag an element from one group to the other. I am able to detect `mouseover` events if I drag an element from group (A) to group (B), but it cannot detect `mouseover` events if I am in the process of dragging an element from group (B) to group (A). And this pattern follows through to further sibling groups that are created after the one from which an element is being dragging. IE: I can drag and detect mouseovers going from A to C and from B to C, but it won't detect mouseover if I'm dragging a C element to either A or B.

I've already attempted `pointer-events:all` and `z-index` (which I'm sure doesn't even work for SVG elements).

Sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/2pku66yu/25/

Attempt to drag one box up and down stream. The downstream elements light up, but the upstream elements don't.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but have you tried changing your `<rect />` tags to `<rect></rect>`?

Comment: Similarly, if you are using a html minifier it may be doing the above for you and causing problems, though I wouldn't expect that problem.

Comment: @xdhmoore I did that for brevity. I'm using D3 to create all of this.

Comment: Can you create something that runs e.g. a jsfiddle or a stack snippet?

Comment: @RobertLongson Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/2pku66yu/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an additional group in the background and reparent the nodes on drag so that they are always in the background. Like so...

```js
var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%");

var data = [ {gind:0, class:"Z",elements:[]},{gind:1,class:"A",elements:[1,2,3]}, {gind:2,class:"B",elements:[1,2,3]} , {gind:3,class:"C",elements:[1,2,3]} ]

var groups = svg.selectAll("gs").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("class",function(d){ return d.class; }).attr("transform",function(d){  return "translate("+d.gind*50+","+d.gind*50+")"});

var elements = groups.selectAll(".element").data(function(d){ return d.elements.map(function(i){ return { id:i , x:i*10, y:i*10 } }); }).enter().append("rect").attr("class","element").attr("transform",function(d){ 
console.log(d)
return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"
}).attr("width",10).attr("height",10).style("fill","#cccccc")

var draghandle = d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object).on("drag", dragfunc).on("dragstart", dragstart).on("dragend", dragend);
var dragging_elem = false;

elements.on("mouseover",function(d){
 d3.select(this).style("fill","red");
}).on("mouseout",function(d){ d3.select(this).style("fill","#cccccc") }).call(draghandle)

var prevParent;
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("Z")[0];

function dragstart(d) {
    prevParent = d3.select(this).node().parentNode;
    d3.select(z).attr("transform", prevParent.getAttribute("transform"));
    z.appendChild(d3.select(this).node());
}
function dragend(d) {
    prevParent.appendChild(d3.select(this).node());
}
function dragfunc(d){ 
  d.x = d3.event.x 
  d.y = d3.event.y
  d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.x+","+d3.event.y+")");  
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! That might be a better solution for my real code!

Answer (score 0):

Found a decent solution to the above example, see new code: https://jsfiddle.net/2pku66yu/47/

```
   var mouse_loc = d3.mouse(svg.node())
    var prev = d3.select(this).style("pointer-events");
   d3.select(this).style("pointer-events","none");

    var el = document.elementFromPoint(mouse_loc[0]+5, mouse_loc[1]+5);

    e2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    e2.initMouseEvent("mouseover",e.bubbles,e.cancelable,e.view, e.detail,e.screenX,e.screenY,e.clientX,e.clientY,e.ctrlKey,e.altKey,e.shiftKey,e.metaKey,e.button,e.relatedTarget);

    if (el) {
        el.dispatchEvent(e2);
    }

    d3.select(this).style("pointer-events","all");
```